# Spring security permitall() works for @RestController but not for @Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application, I have few APIs that I want to allow without authentication. So I added that patterns in the permitall(). But this only works if those patterns are inside the @RestController annotation. If those patterns are in @Controller annotation (I want to return views), Spring asks for the authentication even though they are under permitall().

WebsecutiryConfig class

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/pattern1", "/pattern2").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
}
```

Class with @RestController annotation

```
@RestController
public class RESTClass {

    @GetMapping("/pattern1")
    public String hello() {
        return "my response";
    }
```

Class with @Controller annotation

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

    @GetMapping("/pattern2")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "my view";
    }
```

[image]

[image]
So how can I allow users to see those views without authentication?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. What was happening was that spring was allowing the view file to load without the authentication but it was not allowing to load the related css and js files. So I had to add them to the permitall() pattern.

Comment: Pls share the detailed answer